# Android Check if Service (any) is Running

Tags: android, android-studio, android-service

I have an application that must communicate with another service.
To start it, I want to detect if that Service is running.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you edit your question with more details telling like which service you are trying to get? custom service or internal api service?

Comment: I agree with @Blu it is going to depend on your service, for instance the bluetooth or location services you can run checks at run time to see if they are enabled, then ask the user for permission to access them. Then you can use their service apis.

Comment: Another service created by me. I am using this code on app that must uses the service:
List<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> service = actvityManager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
but I don't obtain the other service running. Maybe, do I have to use some configuration on service?